# Who broke the parshiyot into aliyot and how?

Tags: history, torah-reading, torah-service, provenance

The Torah readings on *Shabbat* are broken into 7 *aliyot*. I know that there are rules for the minimum number of *pesukim* for each *aliyah* but I am wondering who set up the exact placement of the *aliyah* divisions and when (for an annual reading cycle).

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10789) answer posits that the divisions had to do with setting up a learning cycle but that doesn't give any history or specific guidelines. One practical question which develops is, in the case of reading a double *parsha*, why isn't the seventh *aliyah* of the double identical with what would be the seventh *aliyah* of the second *parsha* when it is read on its own? The determination that it should be "seventh" was already made -- why change that when the 2 *parshiyot* are combined? (I note that for a variety of reasons, *aliyot* are not always balanced and even in terms of length so "balance" would not, on its own, appear to be a persuasive answer.)

Comment: https://jewish-faculty.biu.ac.il/files/jewish-faculty/shared/JSIJ4/stulberg.pdf

Comment: "in the case of reading a double _parsha_, why isn't the seventh _aliyah_ of the double identical with what would be the seventh _aliyah_ of the second _parsha_ when it is read on its own?" I fail to see the benefit of this. "The determination that it should be 'seventh' was already made -- why change that": By the same logic, the fourth _aliya_ should stretch from the first _parasha_'s "_r'vii_" to the second's "_chamishi_". +1, though: good question as to provenance of our _aliya_ boundaries.

Comment: @msh210 If, when doubling up, the aliyot must be made larger to include more aterial, the spot for ending shlishi might not allow the "revi'i" when doubled to coincide with the revi'i when not doubled. But, as seen in yesterday's laining, shishi ends a few pesukim short of where shevi'i when single begins. Why not just keep going to an establish shishi/shevi' spot?

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting article, aware of its own limitations, but it points out the unclear history. TY.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In terms of the history of division of Aliyot, you should see Ilana Katzenellenbogen's survey article in *Sinai* 119 (1998), pp. 224-45. She looks at 33 different division customs from the last 1000 years from around the Jewish world and compiles a ~10 page chart with all the different variants from "our common custom" (OCC). Her conclusions are (summarized from p. 225-226):

1. The divisions in various biblical manuscripts are different from OCC and from each other.
2. The divisions in various lists of customs are different from OCC and from each other, but the more recent they are the more they begin to resemble OCC.
3. Her inspection of printed bibles revealed the following strata:

   - From 1517 to 1568: 17 editions, none of which had any division markings.
   - From 1574 to 1702: 22 editions, 13 of which had no division markings and 9 with divisions unlike OCC and unlike each other.
   - From 1702 on: over 100 editions all of which are very similar to OCC (the few differences are found mostly in dividing Parshat Bereishit).

She posits from this that the divisions were originally 'regulated' by local Chazanim and Baalei Keriya usually in separate books of customs, and only in the last 300-400 years has there been a gradual fixation of the division (probably partially influenced by mass printing).

---

While I'm here I'll note that in footnote 5 she collects the relevant Talmudic dicta about where one may make a division (not 1 or 2 verses before or after a parsha break, etc.) including one related to content (Yerushalmi Megilla 3:7):

> זה שהוא עומד לקרות בתורה צריך שיהא פותח בדבר טוב וחותם בהדבר טוב
>   He who comes up to read from the Torah needs to open with a good thing and close with a good thing.

---

Finally I note there were Achronim (notable among them the Vilna Gaon ([Maaseh Rav 132](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA#.D7.A7.D7.9C.D7.91))) who generally opposed respecting the printed division of OCC.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Does the article explain who was the first one to use the OCC? Was it in 1702?

Comment: @shim not that I recall. Also don't confuse the earliest existing printed listing of it with the first people to use it.

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/34103473/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99_%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9D_%D7%99_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%93_%D7%A2%D7%9E_93119

Comment: @DoubleAA Since this recently came to my attention in connection with different answer, I was wondering if you actually have a copy of the purported article from Sinai written by Ilana Katzenellebogen? From what I can determine, no such person existed and the citation is actually concealing the true source. It is from a book entitled (התפילה בישראל בהתפתחותה ההיסטורית) that was written by the Reform Jew, Ismair Elbogen (יצחק משה אלבוגן). It was originally written in German and was published in Hebrew over 25 years after his death by request of his daughter, Shoshana, in Israel & the USA.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/התפילה_בישראל_בהתפתחותה_ההיסטורית

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ismar_Elbogen

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יצחק_משה_אלבוגן

Comment: See footnote 1 to page 93 in the Hebrew article by Weintraub linked in your March 19, 2020 additional comment. In the widely distributed English citations from this article, they incorrectly translate י.מ. אלבוגן as Ilana Katzenellenbogen.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I don't have a copy now but at the time I remember I actually sought out the hardcopy of Sinai 119 to read the article. I have no reason to think she wasn't a real person. Google indicates other articles exist on Judaism topics by an אילנה קצנלנבוגן

Comment: @DoubleAA I appreciate the response. I guess I'm going to have to go for a deep dive in the stacks at the local library to find the actual original journal edition. It appears to be Sinai 118 or 119 (it's cited as both) from 5757, pp.224-245. If I happen to actually find it, would you like photos of the pages linked to your answer?

Comment: @Yaacov edits that add value to a post are generally welcome