# Naso - portion divsion

Tags: chabad, parsha-torah-portion, parshat-nasso

The Chabad Chumash we use has The first portion of Naso to be from 4:21-28. Other Chumash I have (such as the Stone version) have it as 4:21-37. Other random places I look agree with this latter ending point. The second portion in all cases ends at the same point - 4:49.

Can someone explain why there is a difference?

Comment: Curtis Browne, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here!

Comment: The break for the parsha in the Chabad Chumash appears to be following the text as found in the Zhitomer edition of the Mikra'ot Gadolot from 5614 (1859) by the Shapiro brothers. For details about the publishing house, see the following: https://www.jewishpress.com/sections/features/features-on-jewish-world/the-legendary-shapiro-shas/2019/08/15/

Comment: Internal breaks for the 7 readers on Shabbat (if that's what you refer to) are commonly printed nowadays as a suggested convenience and not of much historical significance. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59414/759

Comment: Edot haMizrach usually stop first at the end of the Priestly Blessing to honour the kohen. So what? There are different traditions.