# List of Aliyos with Different Stopping Points

Tags: torah-reading, pentateuch-chumash, mesorah-tradition

Have noticed some Aliyos that seem to be different Mesoros where they should end.

For example

- Bereishis Chamishi - From [4:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.19) -  some go until [4:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.22), others until [4:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.26) (end of Perek)
- Terumah Sheini - From [25:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.17) - some go until [25:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.30), others until [25:40](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.40) (end of Perek)

Does anyone have a complete list of these Aliyos?

*(While aware there are reasons for these discrepancies, more interested in the list itself)*

Comment: How far back do you want to go? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59414/759

Comment: "end of Perek" is a completely irrelevant factor for Judaism (but so is printed aliya break, so I suppose it's slightly possible one affected the other)

Comment: @DoubleAA Saw that answer but couldn't find the chart; I would guess the more recent editions. (Also only wrote "end of Perek" to more easily locate the Pasuk)